# Xcode Cloud fail on ci_post_clone.sh

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcode-cloud

Couldn't find enough information about Xcode cloud and is wondering if anyone is facing any issues using cocoapods with Xcode cloud.

I am aware that I need to add a file called **ci_post_clone.sh** if I have cocoapods.

Almost every time, my Xcode cloud build will fail on the **ci_post_clone.sh** script where according to the log, installing some cocoa pod fail. And the cocoa pod fail varies, each time, a different cocoapod will fail.

For example, below is the log. I never have problem getting **AMPopTip**, **GooglePlaces** error, and this is the first time.I am aware that **AMPopTip** SDK is quite old and its not updated regularly.

I am just trying to understand how common this problem is and how have any of you bypass it.

Some of the things I have done is,

1. Clean, rebuild via Xcode Cloud
2. Run multiple times, each time, error varies and if I am lucky, the build will succeed. So far, I only manage to get 1 successful build out of 5 tries.

[image: First build]
First build

[image: Second build]
Second build

[image: Third build]
Third build

**Xcode cloud environment are**

1. Xcode version: 13.4.1
2. macOS version: macOS Monterey 12.4

**Local machine environment are**

1. Xcode version: 13.4.1
2. macOS version: macOS Monterey 12.4
3. cocoapods version 1.11.3

Comment: I have a same problem. A few weeks ago, the error occurred very rarely, so re-running build solved the problem. However, over the past few days, errors have been occurring with increasing frequency.

Comment: Check the version of XCode and MacOS you're using and try match it in your XCode Cloud workflow.